# How to get own Name & version without AddonManger?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Is it possible for an overlay add-on to get its own **name** & **version** without using the `AddonManager`?

In an overlay add-on, the add-on ID is not automatically provided (like a bootstrapped add-on) and thus has to be entered manually in order to use the `AddonManager`.  At the moment, I parse `install.rdf` for the data.

Is there any alternative method of getting above data?

Comment: Just use `AddonManager.jsm` man, that's the way it's supposed to be done. Is there a reason you can't use it? There was a non jsm way before the jsm was introduced, but its no longer supported.

Comment: As mentioned, `AddonManager.jsm` requires `addon ID` therefore automatic modularization (getting data without user input) is not possible. In other words, the point is not to enter details manually otherwise, instead of entering add-on ID, one might as well manually add name & version and not bother with `AddonManager.jsm`at all. :)

Comment: You can totally get the add id without having to type it. If it's your own addon you can use the `aData` (which also includes selfs addon version, it have has `oldVersion` to tell you which version they had install previously if they had one) or you can iterate through all installed addons of users, is that what you want? I can help you with code to iterate through all installed addons. https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9025999#comment-1120821

Comment: `aData` is only available to bootstrapped addo-ons. The question is about overlay add-ons. :)

Comment: Oh what are you trying to do. Ill help you make it bootstrapped, i have a bunch of templates.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to improve my knowledge of overlay addons.

Comment: Why don't you hardcode in the id of your addon, you're going to know it. Version will chane but id won't.

Comment: True. I have written a number of modules that automatically: get addon name & version, get all it prefs and set to variables, add pref observers and automatically update variables once prefs change, get all strings and set to variables, and all that can be activated with 1/2 lines of code. The modules are self-contained so they can be copy pasted to any overlay addon and they do their job. That is the reason I am trying to minimize manual input. :)

Comment: I see. You gotta share that module man I'm interested in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official API to query add-on information is the `AddonManager`. Anything else are just hacks or work-arounds.

Parsing `install.rdf` for the name is such a hack and has its own problems: The add-on manager may have retrieved e.g. an updated name from an online source, e.g. the addons.mozilla.org website, and as such the `install.rdf`-provided name would be outdated and disagree with the name `about:addons` would show.

I'd argue that *normally* and add-on should know it's own ID. But I recognize that there might be some code meant for reuse (like frameworks) where it would be bad to hard-code the id, i.e. edit the file meant for reuse.

In such cases, parsing `install.rdf` (or some other configuration file) to **get the id** to be used when querying `AddonManager` might be a viable alternative.

There is also the (undocumented on MDN) [`AddonManager.mapURIToAddonID`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/AddonManager.jsm#1707) API, which is used internally to map memory measurements to add-ons in `about:memory`, but which could also be used instead of parsing `install.rdf`, I guess.

Comment: Hey man is there a keyword for like a special directory, you know directory service and FileUtils so like `var methodFU = FileUtils.getFile('ProfD', ['']);` or `var methodDS = DSP.get('ProfD', Ci.nsIFile);`. Maybe some keyword returns the xpi of the self addon?

Comment: I got a long list here: https://gist.github.com/yajd/ed58adda53d5ef513c1f But im no tsure i hit all the keywords. I ran the code I cant find anything with the xpi or restart-ful directory: https://github.com/Noitidart/PortableTester/blob/master/bootstrap.js

Comment: @Noitidart a) What is your question exactly? and b) Why did you post your question as a comment?

Comment: Because it's specifically to try to get this guy what he wants. He wants to get addon from addonmanager without knowing id. or name i guess.

Comment: Thanks Noitidart. I am getting there...slowly but surely :)

Comment: @nmaier isn't this a Catch-22 situation? If the code is id-agnostic how will it point to the right `install.rdf`?

Comment: @paa Well, there are certain ways to figure out the location of the install.rdf by first finding out the URL of the current script and going back from there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok how about this?

Do you know the name of your addon?

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
AddonManager.getAllAddons(function (addons) {
    var cnt = 0;
    console.log(addons)
    for (var i = 0; i < addons.length; i++) {
        if (addons[i].name == 'Adblock Plus') {
            console.log('addons', cnt, addons[i]);
            console.log(addons[i].name);
            console.log(addons[i].id)
            break;
        }
        cnt++
    }
})
```

You're going to have to hard code something, the name, the id, something.

Comment: Thank you Noitidart. Getting the name was the objective ;)  I hardcode a single string which is used uniformly throughout the entire addon from the primary object, to chrome/resource URls, CSS, styles, string-bundles, elements IDs, class names.. all with a single keyword. :)